I have a Thunder e-bike and need advice on bolts in the order they go in etc

I have a Thunder e-tricycle and when I change the tire, I put all the bolts back in and it worked fine for a while, but then all of a sudden the part where the cord comes out, started to turn and would catch and then pull out of socket.
I took everything back apart, and I believe that the inner most threads on the rotor side that goes right into the socket are stripped.  I don’t know what it’s called and when I look for replacement bolt sets there’s pieces that I have that they don’t and it’s very confusing to me.

Is this your bike?   https://richmondebike.com/products/thunder-3-wheel-step-through-fat-tire-e-bike

Which wheel did you remove?  the front or one of the side wheels?   (update) Based on photo of bike, must be the front wheel.  The rear wheels are "single sided"  and are not powered other than by the rider's effort.

That’s a fat tire version of it. Mine is not a fat tire, but it is a front wheel drive tricycle yes just not fat tire like that one.

Partial answer:
Based on the photo, you've removed and reinstalled the front wheel.
The two flanged nuts in your phot will be on the outside, then probably the washer, and inside that are the anti-rotation washers which have a raised section.  Those are intended to fit inside the slot in your fork (also known as the dropout)  and allow the motor to apply torque to the wheel rather than risk spinning on its own axle.
This is probably what has chewed up your wiring, as the motor's power cables will go in through the axle.
The axle in your motor should be stationary relative to the fork, and teh motor should turn around that fixed axle.

The two plastic-looking washers could be from anywhere - I can't tell what order they were in.
If you're not comfortable working with the three-phase AC wiring to your motor, there's nothing wrong with getting this to a Local Bike Shop for a repair.
If the axle's threads are torn off, then you might need a new axle from the manufacturer of your motor, and installation will require disassembly.  If its the nut's thread, they should be a standard size and much easier to replace.
You might consider using threadlocker on marginal threads to try and make them hold, but that has to survive the torque from your motor, but also be light enough to undo the next time you need to change the inner tube.   Don't use high temp threadlocker because the wiring will not survive the heat required to loosen it.  At most use the "hand strength" locktite.
If your motor is just that much too powerful that it always wants to spin the axle, your bike might need "torque arms" to spread the rotational load to the fork rather than just in the narrow area of your dropouts.  Example:

A motor of 250W  or below does not need torque arms, but yours is apparently a 500W bafang and should definitely have torque arms, especially if you've turned up the power levels.

so it’s a purchased e tricycle It never came with torque arms and his worked fine without them until now I understand the way that the washers and spacers go. I believe there’s a different kind of washer that goes inside. The side of the motor with a display goes to grip onto the three teeth that are inside that hole and that’s the part that I’m trying to figure the name out of, every Bolton not that I see online doesn’t have that extra piece and that’s the one that stripped

also, my wiring is still intact. I didn’t do enough of a run for it to really quail around and get pulled on. It’s just that the part in the middle where the wire is attached spins when it didn’t used to and I believe that’s because I don’t have the right bolt or the bolt is stripped that goes in the opposite side of that to connect onto the teeth inside the motor and I think that’s what the extra stripped spacer looking thing is indunno

also in the picture above You can see the two washers with a question mark beside them one of those washers looks like it should have a tab on it. That’s been shared off and that’s the one that I think goes inside the motor to grip onto the teeth that are in there, but I don’t know what that’s called and I can’t find one that looks like that anywhere in the Boldtyou can see the two washers with a question mark beside them one of those washers looks like it should have a tab on it. That’s been shared off and that’s the one that I think goes inside the motor looking at.  sets I’ve been seeing
